# Weird curl+php behaviour

Tags: php, curl, libcurl

My code is pretty simple.

```
function x($url, $request)
{
    static $curl = null;
    if (is_null($curl)) $curl = curl_init($url);
    $options = array(CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array('Content-type: application/json'), CURLOPT_POST => true, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $request);
    curl_setopt_array($curl, $options);
    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    echo curl_getinfo($curl)['total_time'].' ';
}
for ($i=0; $i<10000; $i++) x('http://server/', '<...post vars...>');
```

The problem is that most of the time I get response from the server in 0.0001 sec., but sometimes it is 1.0001 or 2.0001 sec.
The code above may output something like:

> 0.000632 0.00034 **2.001671** 0.000526 0.000501 0.000914 0.007355 0.000769 0.001429 0.001249 0.000554 0.001623 0.000595 0.006834 0.000793 0.000436 0.000408 0.006953 0.000867 0.000593 0.000546 0.007408 0.000837 0.001208 0.000652 0.000947 0.000614 0.000641 0.000647 0.001288 0.000501 0.000582 0.000625 0.000288 0.000351 0.000557 0.000601 0.000259 0.000309 0.000541 0.000565 0.000582 0.000949 0.000403 0.000896 0.000487 0.000569 0.001233 **1.002649** .0.001107

The problem is not with the server, because there is no such delays if I use for example stream_context_create()+fopen(). It seems like the problem in curl itself, but I can't figure out why is it sleeping sometimes for a second or two.

If I use curl_close and reinitialise $curl each time there is no difference - it still hangs sometimes with the same frequency.

Thank you in advance for your reply.

Comment: You have to call `curl_close()`

Comment: Forgot to mention that I have the issue on Debian 7 and OS X Mavericks.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no difference either I use curl_close() or not.

Comment: Are you sure? My thoughts: your bad scripting fills out the connections. After a time no more ports are available and the server waits until he can work again.

Comment: also it can happen before, that it sometimes lasts 1-2 seconds longer. This is then also on the network utilization.

Comment: Absolutely sure. Instead of "static $curl = null;
    if (is_null($curl)) $curl = curl_init($url);" I put just "$curl = curl_init($url);" and add "curl_close($curl)" in the end of the function. The result is the same.

Comment: Well, if it was about bad scripting I would have something like memory leaks or 100% CPU utilising. The weird thing is that when it hangs, it hangs on exactly an integral number of seconds. That means there is some kind of timeout or even special sleep() call to prevent 100% CPU utilising.